# how to turn a for loop with two statements into an inline for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, inline

Is it possible to turn this

```
results = []

for item in response.items:
    new_item = item.__dict__
    new_item["myprop"] = new_item["myprop"].__dict__
    results.append(item.__dict__)
```

into a one line for loop?

The only thing I got to work is:

```
results = [ item.__dict__
            for item in response.items]
        
for item in results:
          item["myprop"] = item["myprop"].__dict__
```

Comment: Why & what's the point? Decreasing the amount of lines does not speed up the program. In fact it makes it more messy and hard to read.

Comment: true, totally forgot about that, it's a stupid question, i just saw all these one liners and thought i have to do something as well

Comment: I mean, it's an intresting question though. I'd like to see how it could be done.

Comment: If you want to try to make code shorter, I'd suggest [code golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/)